# The AST view: Eclipse Plugin does not show nodes of the ATS and says unsupported JLS

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree

I installed AST view Plugin from Eclipse Market Place. I want to use to show the nodes of a java file abstract syntax tree. However, as in the screenshot, it doesn't go beyond Compilation unit node and says : unsupported JLS. I tried switching JLS versions with the right bar. But it keeps showing the same error. [image]

Comment: I have a java file that i want to have the abstract tree syntax shown in the AST view but it won't show and shows this error instead. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Check if the issue can be reproduced in the current Eclipse version without additional plugins (you didn't say which Eclipse version you exactly have, but the screenshot looks like you are one or two releases behind). If you can reproduce it, make sure that the issue has been reported to Eclipse with more details and since you know what an AST is, you might even be able to contribute a fix for this bug.

Comment: I use the latest version of Eclipse which is the current and i tried older versions of Eclipse too but it reproduces

Comment: hello, i installed the AST view plugin manually in the folder plug-in as demonstrated in their website. I also added manually the asked the jdt.core jar in my project and it fixed the problem. I work with eclipse latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i installed the AST view plugin manually in the folder plug-in as demonstrated in their website. I also added manually the asked the jdt.core jar in my project and it fixed the problem. I work with eclipse latest version.